# Mac Terminal opt + left/right key doesn't skip words, gives [D or [C

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I have read [How to skip words in OS X terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/131938/how-to-skip-words-in-os-x-terminal) and while <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>f</kbd> work, <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> will output these annoying [D and [C

I have `Use Option as Meta key` ticked and `⌥←` is set to \033b and \033f for right arrow.

On macOS Sierra, this always used to work, but seems shortly after upgrading to Sierra that this has happened, not sure if it's related though, as my other computer also on Sierra works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, just noticed that I still was on the public beta group, and there was another update to 10.12.1 beta, and after installing this update my issue was fixed.